# Multitouch Trackpad Gestures Dell XPS 15

Tags: 12.04, dell, trackpad, gestures, touchegg

I'm trying to enable some multitouch gestures to mirror what OS X is capable of doing, such as brushing three fingers across the trackpad to switch desktops, swiping two fingers to navigate back in nautilus or firefox etc. I'm trying to use touchegg, but I'm not sure if ubuntu sees my trackpad as a device with more than two finger support. Two finger scrolling works fine.

1. Does touchegg work in Ubuntu 12.04?
2. How can I find out if my trackpad (Dell XPS L502x) supports 3+ finger support in Ubuntu?
3. Are there any compiz plugins that might help?

I have a friend who is trying to achieve the same thing on his Sony Vaio, because he can do most of the aforementioned gestures in Windows.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

Touchegg doesn't work for me in 12.04, and seems its a confirmed bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/touchegg/+bug/918551

As for the rest I have no idea, sorry. Would like to know for my own laptop!